# LINQ does not start with on List<string>

Tags: linq, string

I have a List<string> with five strings in it:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
```

I have another string, "pq", and I need to know if each string in the list does not start with "pq" - how would I do that with LINQ (.NET 4.0)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two options: [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) and [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx). Which one you should use depends on what you find more readable:

```
var allNonPq = myList.All(x => !x.StartsWith("pq"));
var notAnyPq = !myList.Any(x => x.StartsWith("pq"));
```

These are effectively equivalent in efficiency - both will stop as soon as they reach an element starting with "pq" if there is one.

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you could even write your own extension method:

```
public static bool None<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return !source.Any(predicate);
}
```

at which point you'd have:

```
var nonePq = myList.None(x => x.StartsWith("pq"));
```

Whether you find that more readable than the first two is a personal preference, of course :)

Comment: That was awesome, all was where I needed to be. I was super impressed, then I saw 'Jon Skeet' on there. I'm used to being impressed with you, dude.

Answer (score 0):

```
var notPq = from s in myList where  !s.StartsWith("pq") select s;

if (notPq.Any()) {
  // At least one item in list doesn't start with pq, possibly do something with each element that doesn't
}
```

Comment: That doesn't give the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: Downvote is a bit harsh, since another poster also thought he wanted each element that didn't start with pq.

Comment: @Andy: Richard's incorrect misinterpretation was more believable, IMO. If the OP had written 'I need to know each string *that doesn't* begin with "pq"' that would have made sense...

Comment: @Jon:  That is pretty much what he said: "each string in the list _does not start_ with "pq""

Comment: @Andy: No, he said: "I need to know **if** each string in the list...". "If" implies a Boolean result - either overall (as per my answer) or per item (as per Richard's).

Comment: @Jon:  I edited my answer.  Do you think it better answers the question now?

Comment: @Andy: Well, you want `Any()` instead of `Count()` - using `Count() > 0` would be inefficient. But yes, it's better.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool noPQStart = !myList.Any( x=> x.StartsWith("pq"));
```

Comment: downvoter care to explain? This is a working and correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce results which is an IEnumerable<bool>

```
var strings = new string[] { ... };
var results = strings.Select(s => s.StartsWith("pq"));
```

Comment: The OP is after a `bool` answer, I believe.

Comment: @SKeet: it does produce a bool.  The comment should read IEnumerable&lt;bool>.  If did not use &amp;lt;!

Comment: @Richard: It produces an `IEnumerable<bool>` rather than a `bool`. The OP is asking for a single value, as far as I understand it - my first comment says exactly what I want it to say. Perhaps I've misunderstood the question, but I believe the Any/All approach is what the OP is after.

Comment: @Skeet: The question is "I need to know if EACH string contains" ...  "EACH" implies some sort of collection.  Also "contains" implies an boolean.  So I believe the best result is some sort collection of `bool`.

Comment: @Richard: Well we clearly understood the question differently. Hopefully the OP will come back and clarify. To me, "each" can very easily mean "every".